# I am needing to change the table schema without reloading the app domain (EF Model Caching Issue)

Tags: ef-code-first

I have a custom implementation of a multi tenant code first system basically SQL Schema Divisions of the tenants. I am using the ToTable method to map the schema correctly on the first call, but as I have read about the model being cached changing the schema on the second call do a different tenant does not work. Is there any ways in EF 4.1 to disable the caching or to rebuild the model every time.. Yes i know this is not great for performance. Thanks for any help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is an old question, but for all those who face this issue and end up finding this question for a possible solution. Here it goes...

Initially caching could be turned off by setting the "CacheForContextType" property of the ModelBuilder to ‘false’ in the OnModelCreating method. This method is defined in DBContext as virtual and needs to be overridden. But in EF 4.1 this property has been removed, since model creation is an expensive process and the Microsoft team wanted to promote a better pattern. [Check this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/adonetefx/thread/0a794d93-67d1-45de-88dd-cab06267531b)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the Build() command on the ModelBuilder is what you're looking for.

```
modelBuilder.Build().Compile().CreateObjectContext...
```